# How to place Boot strap modal in vertically center aligned manner?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, bootstrap-modal

Hi I have Bootstrap modal.
I am not getting hoe to make vertically center aligned?

```js
 $('#sectionAjaxLoader').modal('show');
```

```html
  <section class="modal" id="sectionAjaxLoader" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <img src='../../Images/ajax_loader.gif' alt="Please Wait..." />
    </section>
```

Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
.modal {
    text-align: center;
}
.modal:before {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: " ";
    height: 100%;
}
.modal-dialog {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9057/

Comment: It is asked to wait couple of min..so i am waiting

Answer (score 0):

**With css only**

```
.modal {
        }
        .vertical-alignment-helper {
            display:table;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .vertical-align-center {
            /* To center vertically */
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .modal-content {
            /* Bootstrap sets the size of the modal in the modal-dialog class, we need to inherit it */
            width:inherit;
            height:inherit;
            /* To center horizontally */
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Demo: [See](http://jsfiddle.net/rensdenobel/sRmLV/13/),
 Another Demo: [See](https://codepen.io/dimbslmh/full/mKfCc)