# Both vertically and horizontally center of Bootsrap ui Modal

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a [Bootstrap ui Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal) that is both vertically and horizontally center align .

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35693444/831294) , that indeed vertically centered the modal , but when I tried it with my own `template` (with 800px) it lost its horizontally center:

i.e - http://plnkr.co/edit/vp3IWIcrpGG6ehH8JKVe?p=preview

How could I achieve this modal with vertically and horizontally center with my own `template` ?

**Note** - The width and height of the `template` is **dynamic** so the solution should be appropriate for any width and and height .

Comment: What about absolute positioning of the modal?

Comment: You can use flex css to get it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMCJjnxn8IM you can video

Comment: Hi, But your `template` is not resizing on window resize. it's just remain 800px and 500px in all screens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49859139/7186739

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason the modal lost its center is due to this css rule:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .modal-dialog {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 30px auto;
    }
}
```

since your template has a 800px width, it overflows its container (the `.modal-dialog` div)

if you set `.modal-dialog` to width: auto it'll be fixed.

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/cYoYOgN1iMUzPKJuBw9H?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I did just override `.modal-dialog` with

```
.modal .modal-dialog {
 max-width: 800px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

this. Because it has fixed `with:600px;` which should be `max-width:800px;`

For smaller screens, I added margin auto so it doesn't go down.

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .modal .modal-dialog{
    margin:10px auto;
  }
}
```

**[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPTgmgf5lis5J9QwxTd0?p=preview)**